# Can you squash multiple changesets in tfs2010 to a single changeset?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have a branch with multiple change sets that I need to code review. I am wondering if there is a way like in git to squash multiple commits into a single commit that contains all the distinct file changes for the task? Or instead of squashing them is there a way to get the distinct changes for all the change sets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changesets are pretty fundamental items. They represent a point in time just as much as they represent a set of changes. It doesn't quite make sense to "squash" them.

You may want to try the [Code Review Sidekick](http://www.attrice.info/cm/tfs/), a free tool. It will allow you to find a set of changesets that you'd like to review, display the individual files and versions contained in them, and to easily perform diffs among the versions (including diffs against the previous versions, even when there is more than one version of the file in the code review).

Comment: Thats what I was afraid of thanks I will have to look into the tool you mentioned. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can go to a specific folder, right-click and choose View History.

Then choose two different changesets (the first and last one you want) by control-clicking, then right-click and choose compare.

This will show you everything that's different between these two changesets.

Comment: Yeah I did know about that thanks. Is there a way that you know of to squash change sets for a task?